# Neighbourhood and metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose that in a metric space $X$ we have $B_r (x)=B_s(y)$ for some $x,y  \in X$ and some positive real numbers $r, s$. Is $x=y$? Is $r=s$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; use the discrete metric on a set $X$:
$$
d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=y$}\\
1 & \text{if $x\ne y$}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $B_2(x)=B_3(y)=X$ for any $x,y\in X$.

Comment: Mentioning for completeness that $X$ should have at least two elements such that we can choose $x\neq y$.

Comment: @Uncountable Well, if the space is a singleton, the OP's assert is true.